# How can I make netbeans identify non-ascii characters given as arguments?

Tags: java, netbeans, unicode, ascii

Let's say I have a simple application which receives a string as an argument and prints it. The problem is when I feed it `αβγδ` (by modifying the project configuration in NetBeans), it prints `?ß??`.

It seems like only the beta (`β`) is kept (and even that seems different). The other characters become question marks. They are not just printed as question marks, they are the actual question mark character (63).

Can Java not handle non-ASCII arguments? Is it NetBeans's fault? Can I do anything about it within NetBeans? What about another IDE?

It seems to me that I should change the encoding somewhere but I've tried different things and none have worked.

I'll edit my question to include a reply I've posted:
"So my question has been marked as duplicate and got a "This question has an answer here" to a thread which does not provide an answer to my question. All of the answers there refer to running java from the command line and I've asked specifically about how to do it in netbeans (or another IDE for that matter)."

Comment: You can find other similar questions and their answers in [this Google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java+command-line+arguments+unicode+site:http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F).

Comment: Trust me, I've googled that and way more and absolutely nothing helped.

Comment: So my question has been marked as duplicate and got a "This question has an answer here" to a thread which does not provide an answer to my question. All of the answers there refer to running java from the command line and I've asked specifically about how to do it in netbeans (or another IDE for that matter).